# How to change the pointing position of a mouse cursor in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I generated a `.cur` file to use it in my `WPF` application, the pointing position by default is left top corner, and I want to set it to the center.

I found some [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550918/change-cursor-hotspot-in-winforms-net) here that help resolve that problem by setting the `HotSpot`s, where you can do stuff like this :

```
public static Cursor CreateCursorNoResize(Bitmap bmp, int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot)
{
        IntPtr ptr = bmp.GetHicon();
        IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
        GetIconInfo(ptr, ref tmp);
        tmp.xHotspot = xHotSpot;
        tmp.yHotspot = yHotSpot;
        tmp.fIcon = false;
        ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);
        return new Cursor(ptr);
}
```

The problem is that is in WindosForms. In WPF the Cursor class constructor doesn't accept a `IntPtr`, it accepts only a `Stream` or `String` (file path).

How can I achieve this in WPF and is there a whole other way to do it ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Custom Cursor Image Hotspot in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447038/set-custom-cursor-image-hotspot-in-wpf)

Comment: @Kami that thread helps you get the `.cur` cursor from a `.ico` I already have it in a `.cur` format, I want to find a solution similar to the Windows Forms one, I hope I explained well

Comment: That is what the linked answer does - please read it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kami mentioned, I had to apply the same logic mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447038/set-custom-cursor-image-hotspot-in-wpf) on my .CUR file and it worked.